# plot_ly 3D plot with constant variable

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to use plot_ly function for 3D plot in R

I have constant date variable in my data which made the plot disappear

In the code below you can see that this problem shows up only with constant date variable

```
#date constant variable
data<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=rep(Sys.Date(),5),z=c(3,2,5,23,6),w=c("a","a","b","b","c"))
p <- plot_ly(x= data[["x"]], y =data[["y"]] , z = data[["z"]], color = data[["w"]], 
             type="scatter3d", mode="markers") 
p


#date not constant variable
data<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=c(rep(Sys.Date(),4),Sys.Date()+1),z=c(3,2,5,23,6),w=c("a","a","b","b","c"))
p <- plot_ly(x= data[["x"]], y =data[["y"]] , z = data[["z"]], color = data[["w"]], 
             type="scatter3d", mode="markers") 
p



#factor constant variable
data<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=rep("A",5),z=c(3,2,5,23,6),w=c("a","a","b","b","c"))
p <- plot_ly(x= data[["x"]], y =data[["y"]] , z = data[["z"]], color = data[["w"]], 
             type="scatter3d", mode="markers") 
p

#numeric constant variable
data<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=rep(1,5),z=c(3,2,5,23,6),w=c("a","a","b","b","c"))
p <- plot_ly(x= data[["x"]], y =data[["y"]] , z = data[["z"]], color = data[["w"]], 
             type="scatter3d", mode="markers") 
p
```

Is there a way to solve this

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Seems maybe like a bug from plotly side but basically the problem is that plotly cannot display large numeric numbers. It applies to 1589392544 (`=as.numeric(Sys.time())`), too. Just add some formatting before the plotting:

```
library(plotly)
data<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 y=rep(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S"),5),
                 z=c(3,2,5,23,6),
                 w=c("a","a","b","b","c"))

p <- plot_ly(data, x=~x, y =~y , z =~z, color = ~w, 
                      type="scatter3d", mode="markers")
p
```